# Custom message in Sitecore Content Editor, Experience Editor, or Launchpad

Tags: sitecore-client, experience-editor, content-editor, launchpad

Is it possible to display a temporary custom message in Sitecore launch pad. The main idea is to reminder/heads up for content authors regarding activities like planned maintenance.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have had a client who needed to inform editors about changes and such. We changed the login page for Sitecore. Added information to the page, they could update from Sitecore. Worked perfectly for them.

Comment: We are using SSO authentication. So user won't see the login page.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As a quick work around, the Sitecore Administrator can add the message to the `Text` field on `/sitecore/client/Applications/Launchpad/PageSettings/TitleText` item in `Core Database`. Once added, the Launch Pad looks something like this:

[image]

Or if you are using CMS Only Mode, I assume adding the text in `/sitecore/client/Applications/Launchpad/PageSettings/TitleText in CMS-Only mode` should work.

Please see if this fulfills your client requirements.

Answer (score 1):

You can quickly achieve this by going to `core` database and opening `Content Editor`.

Navigate to `/sitecore/client/Applications/Launchpad/PageSettings/CustomAnalytics` and change `Text` field to your desired text. This with be header e.g. "Announcements Window".

Then navigate to `/sitecore/client/Applications/Launchpad/PageSettings/FallbackMessage` anf change again `Text` field with your desired text. This will be announced text e.g. "Here goes your announcements".

It will be shown like this at the buttom of the launchpad instead of Custom Analytics:

[image: Launchpad]

Above approach is using what is already there in Sitecore which is not desired in all scenarios.

Best would be to take a look on this article and create your own rendering and add it to Launchpad:
http://kirkegaard-at.blogspot.sk/2015/09/sitecore-launchpad-custom-tiles.html

Comment: I already tried this one. But felt Users will not notice this message.